# How to tell if a logical volume is striped?

Tags: linux, lvm

I created a striped and mirrored logical volume with the following command:

```
$ lvcreate -i 2 -m 1 -L 300M -n lvbig vgdata
```

If I use `lvdisplay` with option `-m` however the output shows that the new volume is mirrored but it does not give information about its stripes. How can I get a complete information about a logical volume which is both striped and mirrored? It seems that `lvdisplay` displays the stripes only if the volume is not at the same time mirrored, instead displaying only mirrors when it is both.

I also tried with the following:

```
$ lvs --segments
```

with the same result: the volume results of a mirror type, no information being also a striped volume.

Answer (score 14):

You can use **lvs** command with additional fields to display the LV layout, including the number of stripes. For example 3 LVs here with stripes used together with raid, mirror and plain striped layout:

```
# lvs -o+lv_layout,stripes
  LV    VG     Attr       LSize   Log          Cpy%Sync Layout      #Str
  lvol0 vg     rwi-a-r---   8.00m              100.00   raid,raid10    4
  lvol1 vg     mwi-a-m---   8.00m [lvol1_mlog] 100.00   mirror         2
  lvol2 vg     -wi-a-----   8.00m                       striped        2
```

If you'd like to see even more, including internal LVs which are used to construct the top-level LV (and their exact layouts), you can use:

```
#lvs -a -o+lv_layout,lv_role,stripes,devices
  LV               VG     Attr       LSize   Log          Cpy%Sync Layout      Role                  #Str Devices                                                                
  lvol0            vg     rwi-a-r---   8.00m              100.00   raid,raid10 public                   4 lvol0_rimage_0(0),lvol0_rimage_1(0),lvol0_rimage_2(0),lvol0_rimage_3(0)
  [lvol0_rimage_0] vg     iwi-aor---   4.00m                       linear      private,raid,image       1 /dev/sda(1)                                                            
  [lvol0_rimage_1] vg     iwi-aor---   4.00m                       linear      private,raid,image       1 /dev/sdb(1)                                                            
  [lvol0_rimage_2] vg     iwi-aor---   4.00m                       linear      private,raid,image       1 /dev/sdc(1)                                                            
  [lvol0_rimage_3] vg     iwi-aor---   4.00m                       linear      private,raid,image       1 /dev/sdd(1)                                                            
  [lvol0_rmeta_0]  vg     ewi-aor---   4.00m                       linear      private,raid,metadata    1 /dev/sda(0)                                                            
  [lvol0_rmeta_1]  vg     ewi-aor---   4.00m                       linear      private,raid,metadata    1 /dev/sdb(0)                                                            
  [lvol0_rmeta_2]  vg     ewi-aor---   4.00m                       linear      private,raid,metadata    1 /dev/sdc(0)                                                            
  [lvol0_rmeta_3]  vg     ewi-aor---   4.00m                       linear      private,raid,metadata    1 /dev/sdd(0)                                                            
  lvol1            vg     mwi-a-m---   8.00m [lvol1_mlog] 100.00   mirror      public                   2 lvol1_mimage_0(0),lvol1_mimage_1(0)                                    
  [lvol1_mimage_0] vg     iwi-aom---   8.00m                       striped     private,mirror,image     2 /dev/sda(2),/dev/sdb(2)                                                
  [lvol1_mimage_1] vg     iwi-aom---   8.00m                       striped     private,mirror,image     2 /dev/sdc(2),/dev/sdd(2)                                                
  [lvol1_mlog]     vg     lwi-aom---   4.00m                       linear      private,mirror,log       1 /dev/sdd(3)                                                            
  lvol2            vg     -wi-a-----   8.00m                       striped     public                   2 /dev/sda(3),/dev/sdb(3)
```

Comment: I do not know what version of `lvm` you have, I installed `lvm2`. If I use `lvs` with the options you suggest I receive a `Unrecognised field: lv_layout`, `Unrecognised field: lv_role`.

Comment: The `lv_layout` and `lv_role` fields are available since lvm2 version 2.02.110 (~ August 2014).